# Velocity Form Tool Disabling

Tags: java, web, velocity

we use velocity, also in our lagecy code there are so many $form vars.

velocity sees the key word form, will call the FormTool to validate the form

and print the java reference on the page.... which is very annoy . how to tell

velocity to disable it?

Comment: What version of VelocityTools are you using?

Comment: version 2.0. I emailed the guy who wrote it. he said there is no way to bypass

Comment: That's not true.  There's always a way.  Question #2.  Do you actually use the VelocityStruts tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VelocityTools 2, you can overwrite tool references by default.  You can also specify your own $form tool that does not do that in your toolbox.  Or even easier, specify "form" as data in your toolbox.  Then the $form reference lookup will find that first for all your pages:

```
<data type="string" key="form" value=""/>
```

Best of all, if you are not using VelocityStruts, then just ditch the full VelocityTools jar and use the VelocityView jar.

Comment: not sure about value="/"  bite, because when we see the $from we do want to rendering stuff , not just ignore it. but ditch the jar should work. but its doggy. the best way is not to name your variable as form or row or table etrc...... a) its meaningless b) it could cause problem like this